# How to get a specific order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table with this data that encodes the information in the next picture.

```
 +----+----------------------------+------+-------+-----------+--------+-------+
| ID |          Element           | Type | LEVEL | ElemOrder | Header | Total |
+----+----------------------------+------+-------+-----------+--------+-------+
|  1 | IncomeStatement            | H    |     1 |         0 | NULL   | NULL  |
|  2 | OperatingIncome            | H    |     2 |         0 | 1      | NULL  |
|  3 | OtherIncome                | H    |     2 |         1 | 1      | NULL  |
|  4 | EarningsBeforeInterestTax  | R    |     2 |         3 | 1      | NULL  |
|  5 | InterestExpense            | R    |     2 |         4 | 1      | NULL  |
|  6 | NetProfitBeforeTax         | R    |     2 |         5 | 1      | NULL  |
|  7 | TaxExpenses                | R    |     2 |         6 | 1      | NULL  |
|  8 | NetProfitAfterTax          | R    |     2 |         7 | 1      | NULL  |
|  9 | DividendPaidShareholders   | R    |     2 |         8 | 1      | NULL  |
| 10 | RetainedEarnings           | R    |     2 |         9 | 1      | NULL  |
| 11 | GrossProfit                | H    |     3 |         0 | 2      | NULL  |
| 12 | OperatingExpense           | H    |     3 |         1 | 2      | NULL  |
| 13 | Revenue                    | R    |     4 |         0 | 11     | NULL  |
| 14 | CostSales                  | R    |     4 |         1 | 11     | NULL  |
| 15 | GrossProfitTotal           | R    |     4 |         2 | 11     | NULL  |
| 16 | SalesMarketingCosts        | R    |     4 |         0 | 12     | NULL  |
| 17 | GeneralAdministrationCosts | R    |     4 |         1 | 12     | NULL  |
| 18 | ResearchDevelopmentCosts   | R    |     4 |         2 | 12     | NULL  |
| 19 | OperatingExpensesTotal     | R    |     4 |         3 | 12     | NULL  |
| 20 | HeaderTotal 11             | T    |     3 |      1000 | NULL   | 11    |
| 21 | HeaderTotal 12             | T    |     3 |      1000 | NULL   | 12    |
| 22 | HeaderTotal 2              | T    |     2 |      1000 | NULL   | 2     |
| 23 | HeaderTotal 3              | T    |     2 |      1000 | NULL   | 3     |
| 24 | HeaderTotal 1              | T    |     1 |      1000 | NULL   | 1     |
+----+----------------------------+------+-------+-----------+--------+-------+
```

[image]

The lines that are element types `H` and `R` are the ones in the image. The lines that are `T` type have been added later.

This structure is actually a tree with all LEAFS of `R`-type and the other nodes, which are parent nodes are `H`-type.

Each `H`-type node should have a corresponding `T`-type node, and these nodes are added at the end.

```
EXPECTED OUTPUT:
```

My problem is that I am trying to get all of the elements in the following order (the way they are displayed in the image, top to bottom, but every H-line has to be closed by a T-line):

```
+----+-------------------------------+------+-------+-------+--------+-------+
| ID |             Name              | Type | Level | Order | Header | Total |
+----+-------------------------------+------+-------+-------+--------+-------+
|  1 | Income Statement              | H    |     1 |     1 | NULL   | NULL  |
|  2 | Operating Income              | H    |     2 |     1 | 1      | NULL  |
| 11 | Gross Profit                  | H    |     3 |     1 | 2      | NULL  |
| 13 | Revenue                       | R    |     4 |     1 | 11     | NULL  |
| 14 | CostSales                     | R    |     4 |     2 | 11     | NULL  |
| 15 | CostThirdParties              | R    |     4 |     3 | 11     | NULL  |
| 16 | GrossProfitTotal              | R    |     4 |     4 | 11     | NULL  |
| 28 | Gross Profit TOTAL NODE       | T    |     3 |     2 | NULL   | 11    |
| 12 | Operating Expenses            | H    |     3 |     3 | 2      | NULL  |
| 17 | SalesMarketingCosts           | R    |     4 |     1 | 12     | NULL  |
| 18 | GeneralAdministrationCosts    | R    |     4 |     2 | 12     | NULL  |
| 19 | ResearchDevelopmentCosts      | R    |     4 |     3 | 12     | NULL  |
| 20 | OperatingExpensesTotal        | R    |     4 |     4 | 12     | NULL  |
| 27 | Operating Expenses TOTAL NODE | T    |     3 |     4 | NULL   | 12    |
| 26 | Operating Income TOTAL NODE   | T    |     2 |     2 | NULL   | 2     |
|  3 | Other Income                  | H    |     2 |     3 | 1      | NULL  |
| 21 | InterestIncome                | R    |     3 |     1 | 3      | NULL  |
| 22 | DividendIncome                | R    |     3 |     2 | 3      | NULL  |
| 23 | OtherIncomeTotal              | R    |     3 |     3 | 3      | NULL  |
| 25 | Other Income TOTAL NODE       | T    |     2 |     4 | NULL   | 3     |
|  4 | EarningsBeforeInterestTax     | R    |     2 |     5 | 1      | NULL  |
|  5 | InterestExpenses              | R    |     2 |     6 | 1      | NULL  |
|  6 | NetProfitBeforeTax            | R    |     2 |     7 | 1      | NULL  |
|  7 | TaxExpenses                   | R    |     2 |     8 | 1      | NULL  |
|  8 | NetProfitAfterTax             | R    |     2 |     9 | 1      | NULL  |
|  9 | DividendPaidShareholders      | R    |     2 |    10 | 1      | NULL  |
| 10 | RetainedEarnings              | R    |     2 |    11 | 1      | NULL  |
| 24 | Income Statement TOTAL NODE   | T    |     1 |     2 | NULL   | 1     |
+----+-------------------------------+------+-------+-------+--------+-------+
```

I tried just to simply ORDER BY specific columns, but I can't seem to find a way. I'm not sure, but I have a feeling I have to go over the table recursively in order to place the TOTAL line where it is supposed to be.

My query is quite simple and is not the point here, I'm trying to find the correct ordering.

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Element,
    Type,
    LEVEL,
    ElemOrder,
    Header,
    Total
FROM myTable
```

Comment: Please, post your query

Comment: @JoeTaras The query is just a simple `SELECT`, but I'm trying to find the correct way to order it in the format that I want.

Comment: What is the logic of expected order?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu What size is your average data set? Is this a report and are there any other tech involved other than just sql server?

Comment: @FeistyMango Just SQL Server unfortunately.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu: I'm trying to find the correct function to calculate the correct path. I think the order field must be different.

Comment: @JoeTaras It's not about HOW it should be different. This is the information I have available. Let's say the T-lines can be moved down one level, but other than that, the data is pretty much static.

Comment: @JoeTaras I'm getting this information from a webservice and I need to parse it with SQL and get it in this specific format.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu: Ok, it's hard :D But at the end.. we'll win ;)

Comment: @JoeTaras I know it's hard, the `ORDER BY CASE` gave me a few ideas, but it's quite complicated to see the pattern and extract the rules from it.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu: Yes, the same problem that I've encountered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't produce a hierarchical ordering without first going to each node of the tree. This is because each node of the tree/row of the table only contains information about itself and its immediate parent; without a full "address" describing where the row is in the final report, there's no way to apply ordering.

Fortunately, we can use the way ASCII strings are ordered to quickly generate an address using set-based logic. Recursion isn't necessary; all we have to do is:

1. Find the root of the tree (in this specific case, header rows without a parent (`HEADER is NULL`) and build the address for the root.
2. Find all nodes who have a parent with an address value, and copy the parent's address to the child node, appending additional information about the child node
3. Repeat step 2 until all nodes are populated with an address.

In your specific case, I was able to simplify things by applying the above to only the header rows; leaves and totals are updated in separate statements.

This will run in SQL Server 2008.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
    ([ID] int, [Element] varchar(26), [Type] varchar(1), [LEVEL] int, [ElemOrder] int, [Header] varchar(4), [Total] varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO mytable
    ([ID], [Element], [Type], [LEVEL], [ElemOrder], [Header], [Total])
VALUES
    (1, 'IncomeStatement', 'H', 1, 0, NULL, NULL),
    (2, 'OperatingIncome', 'H', 2, 0, '1', NULL),
    (3, 'OtherIncome', 'H', 2, 1, '1', NULL),
    (4, 'EarningsBeforeInterestTax', 'R', 2, 3, '1', NULL),
    (5, 'InterestExpense', 'R', 2, 4, '1', NULL),
    (6, 'NetProfitBeforeTax', 'R', 2, 5, '1', NULL),
    (7, 'TaxExpenses', 'R', 2, 6, '1', NULL),
    (8, 'NetProfitAfterTax', 'R', 2, 7, '1', NULL),
    (9, 'DividendPaidShareholders', 'R', 2, 8, '1', NULL),
    (10, 'RetainedEarnings', 'R', 2, 9, '1', NULL),
    (11, 'GrossProfit', 'H', 3, 0, '2', NULL),
    (12, 'OperatingExpense', 'H', 3, 1, '2', NULL),
    (13, 'Revenue', 'R', 4, 0, '11', NULL),
    (14, 'CostSales', 'R', 4, 1, '11', NULL),
    (15, 'GrossProfitTotal', 'R', 4, 2, '11', NULL),
    (16, 'SalesMarketingCosts', 'R', 4, 0, '12', NULL),
    (17, 'GeneralAdministrationCosts', 'R', 4, 1, '12', NULL),
    (18, 'ResearchDevelopmentCosts', 'R', 4, 2, '12', NULL),
    (19, 'OperatingExpensesTotal', 'R', 4, 3, '12', NULL),
    (20, 'HeaderTotal 11', 'T', 3, 1000, NULL, '11'),
    (21, 'HeaderTotal 12', 'T', 3, 1000, NULL, '12'),
    (22, 'HeaderTotal 2', 'T', 2, 1000, NULL, '2'),
    (23, 'HeaderTotal 3', 'T', 2, 1000, NULL, '3'),
    (24, 'HeaderTotal 1', 'T', 1, 1000, NULL, '1')
;




declare @sorttable table (id bigint, sort_order varchar(max) )

insert into @sorttable (id)
select id from mytable


update @sorttable
set sort_order = RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT (varchar(max), id),6)+'.'
where id in (select id from mytable where Header is null and Type = 'h')


while exists (select * from mytable mt
                inner join @sorttable st on mt.ID = st.id where st.sort_order is null and mt.Type = 'H')
BEGIN

update @sorttable
set sort_order = q.sort_order + RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT (varchar(max), q.child_id),6) +'.'
from 
(
    select par_st.sort_order, mt_child.ID as child_id from mytable mt_par
    inner join mytable mt_child on mt_child.Header = mt_par.ID
    inner join @sorttable par_st on mt_par.ID = par_st.id
) q

where q.child_id = id and id in (select id from mytable where Type = 'H')

END

update @sorttable
set sort_order = q.sort_order + RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT (varchar(max), q.child_id),6)
from 
(
    select par_st.sort_order, mt_child.ElemOrder as finalorder, mt_child.ID as child_id from mytable mt_par
    inner join mytable mt_child on mt_child.Header = mt_par.ID
    inner join @sorttable par_st on mt_par.ID = par_st.id
) q

where q.child_id = id and id in (select id from mytable where Type ='R')


update @sorttable
set sort_order = q.sort_order + '999999'
from 
(
    select par_st.sort_order, mt_child.ElemOrder as finalorder, mt_child.ID as child_id from mytable mt_par
    inner join mytable mt_child on mt_child.Total = mt_par.ID
    inner join @sorttable par_st on mt_par.ID = par_st.id
) q
where q.child_id = id and id in (select id from mytable where Type = 'T')

select * from mytable mt
inner join @sorttable st on mt.ID = st.id
order by sort_order
```

[SQLFiddle of solution in operation.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/81f1f/1)

Answer (score 2):

This is the base ordering on type field, you can add other sorting conditions

Try this:

```
SELECT
  ID,
  Element,
  Type,
  LEVEL,
  ElemOrder,
  Header,
  Total
FROM myTable
ORDER BY
CASE 
  when type = 'H' then 1
  when type = 'R' then 2
  when type = 'T' then 3
end
```

Comment: This is almost correct, but the lines with `GrossProfit` and `OperatingExpense` are one after the other, and after `GrossProfit` there should be the nodes under him, `Revenue`, `CostSales`, `GrossProfitTotal` etc.

Comment: Yes, I want to focalize on ORDER BY clause about using of CASE. I'm thinking for the complete solution ;)

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'm trying to figure out from this step too. It's much closer to the end result than I managed to get.